# Are the laws exclusive to the land of Israel, also relevant in terms of what they teach us everywhere?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

There are many laws enumerated in the written and oral Torah. One of their categorizations is those which are obligatory inside the land of Israel and those which are obligatory both in the land of Israel and outside.

The second grouping is what constitutes the Shulchan Aruch.

But *non-obligatory* doesn’t necessarily mean irrelevant. There are many agricultural laws only obligatory in the land, for example.

But is what they oblige us to do inside the land of Israel, also relevant in terms of what they teach us everywhere?

In the overall sense of *good conservatorship*, do those laws indicate to us proper behavior in all places, even though they are not obligatory?

Comment: If I find a law that only applies in israel in Shulchan Aruch, is that a valid answer?

Comment: I edited your title so it is positive; feel free to roll back the edit if you don't approve.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. The Tur and the Shulchan Arukh which follows its structure, are codes of practical law. For their target audiences, these laws aren't practical. Similarly, if there are two valid rulings, the one we don't follow in practice also has what to teach us. As do the stories in the gemara. But they wouldn't go into a practical guide.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It’s fine. I wasn’t specifically trying to limit the discussion to agricultural laws. Nor was I concerned, Micha, with alternative positions to the laws enumerated in Shulchan Aruch which don’t follow the majority. I’m interested to hear discussion about the idea that what drives the obligation in the land of Israel may have relevance and/or benefit outside of Israel. One facet of that discussion is that Torah views that ultimately the borders of Israel will expand to include the whole world.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what you're asking, but after reading it over, are you asking whether one fulfills a Mitzvah if they do an Israel-only Mitzvah outside of Israel? i.e. if I have a farm in my backyard in New York, do I still fulfill a Mitzvah by not plowing it every 7 years, even though there is no obligation to observe Shmittah outside Israel?

Comment: @Salmononius2 No, that is not being asked. Mitzvah does not mean obligation. It means connection or command depending on context. And I didn’t use the term mitzvah at all in the question. I referred specifically to laws (halachot). There are 613 mitzvot. There are countless laws.

Comment: @Salmononius2 It’s more aimed at the underlying reasons behind the laws.